# How to specify translation table name. Globalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize

I've got a translation table for Category model in my app.

I have to create an additional table for model Article::Category with Globalize gem.

Category migration contains follow reversible creation:

```
reversible do |dir|
  dir.up do
    Category.create_translation_table! name: :string,
                                       description: :text
  end

  dir.down do
    Category.drop_translation_table!
  end
end
```

Article::Category migration has almost the same

```
reversible do |dir|
  dir.up do
    Article::Category.create_translation_table! title: :string
  end

  dir.down do
    Article::Category.drop_translation_table!
  end
end
```

When I'm trying to db:migrate I've got an error: `PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "category_translations" already exists`

How to specify table name while module already specified in migration (`Article::Category.create_translion_table!`)

There is no method or option in globalize gem to specify table name. I wish to do it without overriding Article::Category class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding

```
def self.table_name_prefix
  'article_'
end
```

In Article module declaration

```
module Article
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'article_'
  end
end
```